# Submit button not sending form data to mysql - jquery issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

My jquery validation script is below. When i click the submit button it does not submit the form data to mysql. The submit button is called submit. If I remove the jquery validation script it submits to mysql so it is an issue with the validation script.

Jquery Validation script:

```
$(function() {
    function validate(id) {
        var enabled = ($("input[name='attendance" + id + "']:checked").val() == 'Yes');
        if (enabled) {
            //Please select option is selected              
            if ($("#food" + id)[0].selectedIndex == 0 || $("#drink" + id)[0].selectedIndex == 0) {
                alert('Please select color');
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };

    $("input[name^='attendance']").click(function(e) {

        var id = this.name.replace('attendance', '');
        $("#food" + id + ", #drink" + id).prop("disabled", this.value == 'No');
        validate(id);
    });

    $("input:submit").click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var retVal = false;
        $.each([1, 2], function(i, val) {
            retVal = (validate(val) || retVal);
        });
        if (retVal) {
            $('list').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

form data:

```
<form name="colour" action="" method="post" id="list">
```

Comment: ...why are you using 6 UPDATE queries to update one row?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question as to why you would do that instead of just one query. A solution is not good just because "it works".

Comment: @Jacob consider this a downvote to your comment. You could reduce the amount of code by a factor of 6.

Comment: its not that i am worried about. When jquery validation is removed it submits all my form info to mysql so It works fine so why change it! it is the jquery that is the issue

Answer (score 1):

The selector in the `submit()` is incorrect.  You're looking for the form by its id, `list`. Your selector is looking for tags called `<list>`.

```
if(retVal){$('list').submit();}
// Should be
if(retVal){$('#list').submit();}
```

Update: if it won't submit in IE:

```
if (retVal) {
  document.getElementById('list').submit();
}
```

#### Update 2:

Instead of binding this to the submit button's `.click()`, bind it to the form's `.submit()` and return true or false:

```
// Bind to the form's .submit()
$("#list").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var retVal = false;
    $.each([1, 2], function(i, val) {
        retVal = (validate(val) || retVal);
    });
    // return the true/false to the submit action
    // false will prevent submission.
    return retVal;
});
```

Comment: I have changed it to what you said however it still does not submit. On internet explorer there is an error (button right). Line 3 'Object doesnt support this property or method'. When I remove the '#' I do not get this error. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jacob According to docs (http://api.jquery.com/submit/), the `submit` attribute doesn't bubble up in IE. You can do it with a simple javascript call. See above.

Comment: thanks but it still not submitting. getting same error but differnet line 173

Comment: I have made new code http://pastebin.com/pGb8MDNZ. This code submits but if 'please select' is selected when submit is clicked the validation error occurs and it redirects to the page i requested in my php. So i need to prvent it from going to the page in php if 'please select' is selected when submit is clicked

Comment: Haven't given up, but it may require a lengthy answer I don't have time to undertake right now.

Comment: I thought it would have been a simple line of code that would just beed to be changed

Comment: thnx that bypasses the validation error so nothing pops up if please select is selected and submit is clicked. with this code here: http://pastebin.com/pGb8MDNZ is the closest i have got. if both of the radio buttons are 'yes' and dropdowns are please selected it does not redirect to index.html. if one is yes and at please select and the other is at no it will go onto index.html.

Comment: on your update code 2 if the 'no' radio button is selected the drop down menus are not greyed out. IE error says expected '}' line 178